# Google Pay with Stripe doesnt work for Android App

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

Followed the Stripe documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay?platform=android#native

Step 1:

```
<application>
  ...
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
    android:value="true" />
</application>
```

Step 2:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.19.2'
}
```

Step 3:

```
public class CheckoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button googlePayButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.checkout_activity);

        PaymentConfiguration.init(this, PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

        googlePayButton = findViewById(R.id.google_pay_button);

        final GooglePayLauncher googlePayLauncher = new GooglePayLauncher(
                this,
                new GooglePayLauncher.Config(
                        GooglePayEnvironment.Test,
                        "IN",
                        "My Store",
                        false,
                        new GooglePayLauncher.BillingAddressConfig(),
                        false,
                        false
                ),
                this::onGooglePayReady,
                this::onGooglePayResult
        );

        // launch `GooglePayLauncher` to confirm a Payment Intent
        googlePayButton.setOnClickListener(
                v -> googlePayLauncher.presentForPaymentIntent(clientSecret)
        );
    }

    private void onGooglePayReady(boolean isReady) {
        // implemented below
    }

    private void onGooglePayResult(@NotNull GooglePayLauncher.Result result) {
        // implemented below
    }
}
```

But found that the Gpay app is not opening up. The screen blinks and closes again. Google Pay with Stripe isnt working up.

Comment: You may need to elaborate more on the behavior. What is `isReady` returned on onGooglePayReady? Was `presentForPaymentIntent` called and then which screen blinked and closed? Probably that's GooglePay in India and different with the GooglePay Stripe supports (reach out to Stripe Support for clarifications)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of brainstorming finally found answer in their support url: Stripe Gpay is not supported in India. This is very bad if you arent supporting it in India just disable the option on your website with a basic info to user.
Cant accept such things from Stripe.

FYR: https://support.stripe.com/questions/supported-payment-methods-currencies-and-businesses-for-stripe-accounts-in-india